# VBA: Why must I set focus to control every time?

Tags: ms-access, properties, ms-access-2007, vba

I am creating a personal Library Inventory system using an Access 2007 database. In code, whenever I reference the `.Text` property of a form control, whether it be changing the value, or simply checking the value in an IF statement, I get prompted with `Run-time error '2185': You can't reference a property or method for a control unless the control has the focus`.

Why is this?

For setting the `.Text` it's not a huge deal, but when I'm checking the value in an IF statement, I can't set the focus when I'm checking multiple conditions.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use `.Value` instead - that doesn't require setting focus first.  From the documentation, for example for the [TextBox control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822552.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> While the control has the focus, the Text property contains the text
>   data currently in the control; the Value property contains the last
>   saved data for the control. When you move the focus to another
>   control, the control's data is updated, and the Value property is set
>   to this new value. **The Text property setting is then unavailable until
>   the control gets the focus again.**

Comment: Thanks! Been awhile since I worked in Access. Knew there had to be something small I was overlooking.