# Populate a text box on a button click

Tags: vba, ms-access

In MS Access 2016 I am trying populate a text box on a form, when someone clicks a button on the form.

The button, Command9 - I have set the OnClick event to [Event Procedure], which then created the following:

```
Private Sub Command9_Click()
End Sub
```

I added:

```
Private Sub Command9_Click()
  Me(Field1) = "hello"
End Sub
```

I also tried:

```
Private Sub Command9_Click()
  Field1.text = "hello"
End Sub
```

I get the error:

> You can't reference a property or method for a control unless the control has the focus

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17306200/vba-why-must-i-set-focus-to-control-every-time), use `.Value` vs `.text`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many, many ways to do this:

The most minimal way, by using the fact that all controls are available as private variables in the form module:

```
Private Sub Command9_Click()
    Field1= "hello"
End Sub
```

By using the `.Value` property to explicitly set the value:

```
Private Sub Command9_Click()
    Field1.Value= "hello"
End Sub
```

Using the fact that the controls are available as properties of the form:

```
Private Sub Command9_Click()
    Me.Field1= "hello"
    'Or Me.Field1.Value = "hello"
End Sub
```

Using the `Form.Controls` collection:

```
Me.Controls("Field1") = "hello"
Me.Controls("Field1").Value = "hello"
```

Using the bang (`!`) operator to implicitly use the controls collection:

```
Me!Field1 = "hello"
Me!Field1.Value = "hello"
```

All these approaches should reach exactly the same goal.