# Access VBA - If/Else statement keeps giving me an error but I can’t figure out why

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have two subform (subfrmA and subfrmB)and a main form frmAB. Both subforms are invisible until the user selects what form they want from comboboxAB on the main form. So if user selects Form A in the main form comboboxAB, subfrmA will become visible while subfrmB remains invisible. Then user inputs changes saves and exits.

But when the form is opened back up, I want the forms of the saved records to automatically load so I wrote the below code.

```
    Private Sub Form_Load ()
    If Me.comboboxAB.Text = “Form A” Then 
       Me.subfrmA.Visible = True
       Me.subfrmB.Visible = False
       Me.subfrmA.SourceObject = “Form.Form A” 
    ElseIf Me.comboboxAB.Text = “Form B” Then 
       Me.subfrmB.Visible = True
       Me.subfrmA.Visible = False
       Me.subfrmB.SourceObject = “Form.Form B” 
    End If
    End Sub
```

However, I get an error. “Run-time error ‘2185’: You can’t reference a property or method for a control unless the control has the focus.”

And the code:

```
    If Me.comboboxAB.Text = “Form A” Then
```

Is highlighted does anyone know why this is? Also I typed the code up on my tablet, so the quotes in my code look like smart quotes but they are not.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17306200/vba-why-must-i-set-focus-to-control-every-time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using .Value instead of .Text , if i remember correctly the .Text property is only available when focused (which is what that errormessage hints at).

That is to say, you could use .Text in Subs that relate to the Combobox itself being changed, but not within your Form_Load Sub, as that one relates to the Form and not the Combobox itself.